# Unable to get object of array by index

Tags: php, arrays

**EDITED:**
I am generating a 2D array and storing it in db as json string. When I need to modify anything in the array, I then fetch the json string and decode it like

`$myarray = (array)json_decode($jsonString);`

The dump of array is as

[image]

```
$index = 2;
```

When I wan to access object at index '2' like `$myarray[$index]` I get `null`. Please guide what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code that fails cannot possibly match your description. Please upload a sample (e.g. at ideone.com) that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/M0SIY4G5

Comment: It has stdClass objects as elements, for normal elements it works but not with stdClass objects

Comment: Why did you attach a screenshot of the array, and not text?

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with the question, that everyone is down voting it?? I just asked a question with reasonable input

Comment: Even with `stdClass` objects, this should work fine: http://codepad.org/0exRi6zc.  Are those the only 3 elements in the array?

Comment: What I am doing is saving the 2d array as json string, when I retrieve it becomes like that and then I can't access the object on particular index

Comment: @makki: Try using `json_decode($string, true)`.  The 2nd parameter tells it to convert all objects into arrays.  Maybe the main "array" is really an object?

Comment: @makki: Not to be mean, but these are the kinds of things you should include when you 1st ask your question. :-P

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the guidance. I will be careful next time.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: But just for understanding, why it didn't worked without using the `true` flag in the `json_decode`?

Comment: @makki: Because it returned you a `stdClass` object instead of an array.  You probably have errors suppressed in your PHP.  You should have seen a warning about using an object as an array.

Comment: I converted it to array with type casting, `(array) json_decode($string)` but still it wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you said this "array" was decoded from JSON.  When you use `json_decode`, send `true` as the 2nd parameter.  That tells it to make arrays instead of objects when decoding.

You're having trouble because the array is being decoded as an object, which you access using `->` instead of `[]`.

```
$newArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

**UPDATE**: You were trying to do `(array)json_decode($jsonString)` and that wasn't working.  That's because PHP is silly when it comes to type-casting.

Here's a quote from the PHP docs:

> If an *object is converted to an array*, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: **integer properties are
>   unaccessible**; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.
>   This can result in some unexpected behaviour.

<sub>Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting</sub>

So, it wasn't working because PHP said so.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But when I tried to get object after converting it to array by type casting `(array)json_decode($string)` it still didn't work. 
Using your solution it worked, but why it didn't work when I type casted? That's what troubling me...

Comment: @makki: I don't actually know >.>

Comment: @makki: I found it!  It's because of how PHP's type-casting works.  Here's a quote from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting): `If an object is converted to an array, ... integer properties are unaccessible`.  So, `(array)json_decode($string)` didn't work because PHP is silly.

Comment: You're my star @Rocket Hazmat. Thanks again for helping/guiding me completely!

Comment: @makki: No problem!  I love to help out :-)

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$index = '2';
```

I think you defined the array as associative.